# Get different scopes for an employee

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am retrieving the different roles/scopes of an employee using a dynamic query like below :

```
  DECLARE @roles NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
        DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
        Scope NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    SELECT @roles=@roles+ 'Select '+isnull(er.ColumnName,'*')+' from '+er.SchemaName+'.'+er.TableName+' where '+kcu.COLUMN_NAME +'='+er1.ValueId 


       from [Function].[Role] er 
        left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc on 
            tc.TABLE_NAME=er.TableName and tc.TABLE_SCHEMA=er.SchemaName
       left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu on kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME=tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        left JOIN Employee_Role er1 ON er.EntityRoleId = er1.RoleId
        left  JOIN Employee e ON er1.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
    where e.EmployeeId=54 AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='PRIMARY KEY' AND er1.ValueId !=0 AND er1.ValueId IS NOT NULL

    INSERT INTO @table(Scope)
  EXEC sp_executesql @roles;

  SELECT * FROM @table
```

This is my output :

[image]

When I try to display the `EmployeeId` with roles (scopes) like below :

```
DECLARE @roles NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
    DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    Scope NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

    SELECT  e.EmployeeId,

'Select '+isnull(er.ColumnName,'*')+' from '+er.SchemaName+'.'+er.TableName+' where '+kcu.COLUMN_NAME +'='+er1.ValueId 


       from [Function].[Role] er 
        left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc on 
            tc.TABLE_NAME=er.TableName and tc.TABLE_SCHEMA=er.SchemaName
       left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu on kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME=tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        left JOIN Employee_Role er1 ON er.EntityRoleId = er1.RoleId
        left  JOIN Employee e ON er1.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
    where e.EmployeeId=54 AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='PRIMARY KEY' AND er1.ValueId !=0 AND er1.ValueId IS NOT NULL

    INSERT INTO @table(Scope)
  EXEC sp_executesql @roles;

  SELECT * FROM @table
```

My output is empty.
Expected output :

[image]

Comment: I think it is data related. Try commenting out the where clause, and double check the joins. But still, if you can give a sample data, it will be easy to identify and fix the issue.

Comment: Why are you storing the database schema and database table name in the Role table? This is a big red flag that your data schema is the root of the problem here.

Comment: @SeanLange I did not  I'm working on ETL. I am just collecting data from staging area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second query, you left out this:

```
...@roles=@roles+ ...
```

Comment: If I add it I get the following error 'SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations'

Comment: Your approach is fundamentally flawed.  You can't SELECT `EmployeeID` separately from the `@roles` query string, you have to find a way to include `EmployeeID` in that string.  Your SELECT query needs to do nothing but construct the `@roles` query string.